Will there be magnetic induction between two parallel straight wires and only one of them carrying current?
If two coil is placed parallel and only one of them is conducting the current we can see some current flowing in the other one due to the magnetic flux changing in the current carrying coil. This is similar to transformer step up or step down. Am I right?
Also when two straight wires placed parallel,both carrying current in the same direction have a attraction force between two wires due to the magnetic field of the two wires overlapping with each other. I am clear with this too.

Now if among two straight wires placed parallel, only one is carrying current say A and other one B is placed within the magnetic field created by the current carrying wire A, will B carries some current due to the magnetic field/flux it was influenced?
And if yes is this effect is similar(values of current carried may not be same due to dimensions) to the transformer?
And if it is similar to transformer then the distance between two coils primary and secondary in transformer is also a factor for the efficiency of transformer?

